# Seeing a man about a dog: idiomatic approaches to avoiding personal explanations

Tags: idiomaticity

There is an [expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/See_a_man_about_a_dog) in (British) English along the lines of

> I have to go and see a man about a dog.

It is the thing you might say, for example, when leaving a gathering of friends at the pub and you want to forestall any enquiry about what you will be doing, or why you have to leave. It is different from saying, "Mind your own business!" specifically because it can be used pre-emptively. It is also much more friendly.

Is there a similar idiomatic approach in German? ... and in addition, how *does* one tell someone to mind their own business!

N.B. Thanks to @RDBury in the comments below for the link to the Wikipedia explanation!

Comment: Certainly not idiomatic: _Ich muss mal nach den Hühnern schauen!_ (especially if everyone knows that you don't keep any).

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/See_a_man_about_a_dog).

Comment: *Kümmere dich um deinen eigenen Kram* is an informal way of saying "Mind your own business." *Kram* on it's own is a very usefully vague word meaning "stuff", "things", "affairs", etc.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the acknowledgment. It's nice to know the comments were helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> Ich muss noch etwas erledigen!

is a common statement in this case.

Comment: mind their own business! - part is missing

Comment: @mic: I don't think so - the fact that you are so unspecific already implies you do not want to volunteer more information.

Comment: @mic: Was andere _dir_ gesagt haben, sagst du jetzt anderen. Richtig? – Die Antwort bleibt, wie sie ist. Im Übrigen kannst du den Rest in einem eigenen Text verarbeiten.

Comment: In Britain, "Execuse me, there's something else I have to do" would definitely *not* forestall the question "What [do you have to do so urgently]?" . In contrast, *seeing a man about a dog* is a complete (albeit false) explanation for one's departure that forestalls further enquiry. How do people respond to "Ich muss noch etwas erledigen"?

Comment: @user02814: Usually there is no question _»What?«_ on _»Ich muss noch etwas erledigen«_, otherwise I wouldn't have made an answer out of it.

Comment: I'd say _often_ there'll be no question asked, but certainly there _might_ be a “das kann doch bis morgen warten!” or “was hast du denn _um diese Zeit_ wichtiges zu erledigen?”

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Wie Leute reagieren, kann man letztlich nicht bestimmen; im Allgemeinen wird die Floskel aber so verstanden, wie sie gemeint ist: als Signal, nicht weiter gefragt werden zu wollen.